# How to do math with dates in MM/DD/YYYY format?

Tags: bash, shell, date

I have a file that contains a list of dates in `MM/DD/YYY` format. Each of these is stored in a `$date_variable` inside a while loop. I also have:

`current_date="$( date +%x )"`

I need to compare the dates from the file to the `$current_date`.

How can I say "if current date = $date_variable + at least 7 days? or "if at least 7 days have passed since $date_variable, then do this".

I have tried working with "if" comparison operators, but I don't get the expected result because of the format of `$date_variable`.

Also, I find it hard to change the format of `$date_variable` because they are being taken from a webpage with `curl` and `grep`.

EDIT:

My script looks like this:

```
# Store current date in the MM/DD/YYYY format
current_date="$( date +%x )"

# Iterate each line from hotfix_final and read the variables hf_link and release_date
while read -r hf_link release_date; do

  # Install hotfixes on POC machines
  if [ "$current_date" > "$release_date" ]; then
    wget "$hf_link"
  fi

done </home/abc/hotfix_final # Set the file as input for the whole while loop
```

hotfix_final:

```
https://download.abc.com/hotfix 06/24/2019
https://download.abc.com/hotfix2 06/26/2019
```

and I'd like to say:

`if "$current_date" = "$release_date" + at least 7 days; then ...; fi`

Comment: IMO, You don't. Use an ISO standard that's string comparable instead.

Comment: You don't; you convert them to a properly machine-readable format and then convert back when you have done your arithmetic. How exactly to do that depends on which `date` version you have; many answers here assume GNU `date` which is pretty universally available but not the default on many non-Linux platforms.

Comment: input dates look like these: ```06/24/2018```, ```02/04/2019```, ```02/15/2019```, ```03/29/2019```. ```GNU``` date is an option for me.